# Is there a way to create and train a model without transfer learning using tensorflow object-detection api?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api, transfer-learning

I'm using faster_rcnn_resnet50 to train a model which will detect corrosions in images and I want to train a model from scratch instead of using transfer learning.

I don't know if this right but the reason I want to do this is that the already existing weights (which are trained on COCO) will affect my model trained on corrosion images.

One way I would like to do this is randomize or unfreeze the weights of the feature extractor on the resnet50 and then train the model on my images.

but there's no function or an option in the resnet50 config file to randomize or unfreeze weights.

I've made a new labelmap with a single label and tried it with transfer learning. It's working but I would like to have a model is trained just on my images and the previous weights shouldn't affect my predictions.

This is the first time I'm working with object detection and transfer learning. Will the weights of the pre-trained model on COCO affect my model which is trained on custom images of corrosion? How do you use tensorflow object-detection API without transfer learning?

Comment: You can train from scratch by configuring the pipeline.config file, in `train_config`, remove the line `fine_tune_checkpoint : ` then the weights of the feature extractor (resnet50) will be randomly initialized

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I've trained my model on COCO for 200k steps but the results were pretty bad. It was only detecting people and with very low accuracy.

Comment: Hi @keshavN, I have been trying to learn how to train an object detection model from scratch without using transfer learning.  But, as I'm sure you know, there is almost no information out there on how to do this.  Can you please share the link where you downloaded the ResNet50 model from?  I would like to use it to also train on my own data set; thank you.